# Ingresar una fecha en java java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""

Tags: java, date

Soy relativamente nuevo en java y estoy haciendo una cuenta bancaria, pero necesito ingresar una fecha para que se guarde en un arraylist para la cuenta de banco, pero al momento de querer ingresar la fecha no me deja ingresarla y me salta el siguiente error:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: ""
```

La parte del codigo de la fecha es esta:

```
System.out.print("Ingrese la fecha de alta DD/MM/AAAA: ");
String T = scanner.nextLine();
Date fecha = ParseFecha(T);
```

Y para hacer la conversion fue con `import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`

Este seria el metodo con el que me da error: 
        `public static Date ParseFecha(String fecha)
        {
        SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date fechaDate = null;
        try {
            fechaDate = formato.parse(fecha);
        }
        catch (ParseException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
        return fechaDate;
        }`

Comment: Tienes que mostrar tu método ParseFecha, que es donde se intenta hacer la conversión.
Y por cierto, tanto variables como nombres de métodos comienzan siempre con mínúsculas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas tratanto de convertir "" a un valor Date, esto no es posible, por esta razón obtienes el error `ParseException`.

Valida tu método para atrape el tipo de error `ParseException` y en este caso que retorne una instancia de Date() con el valor actual (o un valor null) en caso de obtener este error, por ejemplo :

```
 private static Date ParseFecha(String sDate){
       try {           
           Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(sDate);      
           return date;
       } catch (ParseException ex) {
           return new Date();
           //return null;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Wow! Esta geniaal que agregue la fecha actual automáticamente, pero como seria si lo quiero agregar manualmente? Gracias!

Comment: Simplemente llama el mètodo por ejemplo: System.out.print("Fecha: " + ParseFecha("29/05/2020"));